# Detecting the ViewChanged event of the ScrollViewer inside a GridView in windows 10

Tags: c#, gridview, winrt-xaml, uwp

I am creating a windows 10 UWP app. 
I have a GridView

```
  <GridView x:Name="gv" Margin="8,20,8,8" 
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemClick="gv_ItemClick"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  SizeChanged="GridView_SizeChanged"
                  SelectionMode="Single">

                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>

                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <Image Source="{Binding thumbnailPath}"
                                   Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

Since there is already an scrollviewer inside I would like to trigger the viewchanged event of this scrollviewer.

I have already tried,

```
var scrollViewer = gv.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
```

and

```
ScrollViewer scroll = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<ScrollViewer>(gv);
```

Both seem to return null references!
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question will help you :

[Detecting a scroll event in GridView (Windows 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517993/detecting-a-scroll-event-in-gridview-windows-8)

You can do it by : GetFirstDescendantOfType and GetDescendantsOfType extension methods in WinRT XAML Toolkit .

Please see this post : http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/WinRT-XAML-Automatically-Scrolling-ListView-to-Bottom-and-Detecting-When-ListView-is-Scrolled

**UPDATE :**

In same question, there is a good workaround :

> Edit a template of the GridView, and look inside the XAML to find a
>   ScrollViewer which is a component of the GridView.
>
> The ScrollViewer has a ViewChanged event that you can subscribe to.
>   Now whenever the GridView is scrolled, this event will be fired.

Try that!

Comment: I tried GetFirstDescendantOfType but it returns null.